# Google Chrome does not quit nicely

Tags: google-chrome

When Google Chrome opens, it displays a message that says that it **"did not shut down properly"**. This happens everytime I open it, after booting the computer or just after closing the browser with the X. There is a button that offers me to open the recent tabs, but the button does not work and Chrome does not find anything, I end up on a blank page.

In order to solve my problems, I tried to turn off my extensions and that kind of things, but I found out that it does not work. Plus, the changes are not saved in Chrome apparently, I suggest that it is because it does not close properly.

I would like to solve this problem without removing and re-installing Chrome because I have a lot of stuff saved in my bookmarks and the configuration of my address bar*. The problem started out of the blue, not after any update or anything. I want it to be solved because I need to have access to my recently closed tabs when the browser opens.

I tried to update with the current stable version of Chrome but it did not change anything.

*Edit: my Address bar has search engines configured (maps, language translation, wikipedia...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possibilities is that your browser's profile has been corrupted. Without doing anything that could cause you to lose data, you could try making a new profile as described here: [Create a new browser user profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059) in the *section on Linux*.

But, in short (although you should read the link above completely),

- Make sure that Chrome is not running at all.
- Rename `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` to
  `~/.config/google-chrome/Default.bak`.
- Start Chrome. See if your problem is fixed.

Note that `.config` is a hidden folder. You'll need to enable viewing of hidden files and folders in your File Manager. Of course, if you use the command line, you could run something like:

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome/Default ~/.config/google-chrome/Default.bak
```

**If** your problem is fixed, gradually copy over *only files that you absolutely need* (because some of them may be responsible for your problem in the first place) from `Default.bak` to the new `Default` folder that Chrome automatically creates.

Further, since you need your bookmarks, they are stored as a simple text file called `Bookmarks` in the `Default` folder so copying them over from `Default.bak` to the new `Default` should probably not break anything and give you back your bookmarks. Again, *it's better to do this when Chrome is not running at all*.

As for "configuration of my address bar", I don't know what that means. Perhaps you may want to edit your question to explain that aspect.

Edit: if you don't want to go the "new profile" route and if you have another Google account, you may try adding a new user. That option is available in `chrome://settings`. Do take look at the options which include importing stuff from another profile!

[image: New User]

Comment: Thanks, I can not say that it worked because it kind of started working again by itself 24 hours later. But I had created a new profile at some point before that happened.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. I don't mind reinstalling chrome since I have everything sync with my Google account. I've delete my profile and created new ones, but I keep seeing this error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar issue where it displayed "did not shut down properly" every time after booting up. 
For me this was happening due to Google Chrome running in the background even after closing it, as this was the default setup after installation.

I fixed it by going to the Advanced settings in chrome **" Settings -> System -> Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"** and unchecking the box beside it.

Comment: By far the simplest answer and worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

This was happening to me too and it was driving me crazy!

In my situation (trusty), this had nothing to do with user profiles. My issue was that the desktop environment was shutting down prior to the background chrome process; this caused chrome to 'ungracefully' exit and bug me about it with each restart.

Some of the solutions you find on line get around this by never letting chrome run as a background process, which was an unacceptable trade off for me.

I fixed it on my system by adding a stanza to the Upstart script for the desktop manager (Lightdm). You need to edit `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` as root:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following at the end of the file:

```
pre-stop script
    pkill --oldest chrome
    sleep 2
end script
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I had to  reboot twice before seeing this work.  I believe editing the lightdm.conf file does not take effect until a reboot.

Comment: I have restarted twice with no effect. I have also increased the sleep to 5. Is there something I need to do differently for Xenial?

Comment: I've been trying to use this approach in Ubuntu 18.04 without success, I can't find any way to plug the call to `pkill` before the system signals Chrome to stop. Any had success?.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it stemmed from `gnome-keyring-daemon` which was syncing data over internet and daemon keeps running in the background.

To fix it, run it with `chrome --password-store=basic  --disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1` switches. It fixes the above annoying message.

Answer (score 0):

Still a problem after all these years and no workarounds work for me.

My workaround was to bind a script to the press of the laptop power button that runs instead of the normal shutdown (changed to `When the power button is pressed: 'Do_nothing'` in Settings/Power Manager) and then:

```
$ sudo nano /bin/shutdownc
$ sudo cat /bin/shutdownc 
#!/bin/sh
pkill --oldest chrome
sleep 3
shutdown now

$ sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/power
$ sudo cat /etc/acpi/events/power
event=button/power
action=/bin/shutdownc

$ sudo service acpid restart
```