# Want chrome close normally when shutdown or reboot ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scripts, google-chrome, shutdown, reboot

**Problem:** When I reboot or shutdown ubuntu, and have chrome opened, I think chrome close normally, but not, and after start ubuntu and reopen chrome  it say: chrome has closet anomaly, and you want to restore tabs?(something like that.).

**Want:** close chrome normally before shutdown or reboot, and start normally without error message about anomaly close.

I try to create an init script and it didn't work, I reboot or shutdown Ubuntu with chrome opened, then start chrome and test open chrome and see if it closed normally, but it din't.

**Script for close Chrome**

```
#!/bin/sh
killall -1 chrome
```

**Path of script**

```
# path script
etc/init.d/closeChrome
```

**How I create**

```
# how I create script for reboot and shutdown
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/closeChrome /etc/rc0.d/K00closeChrome
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/closeChrome /etc/rc6.d/K00closeChrome
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/closeChrome
```

**Update 31/12/2018:** The script does its function, it execute before Ubuntu shutdown, but I think chrome close before script starts, maybe Ubuntu close sessions and their programs.

**Upate 05/01/2019:** Try to reinstall chrome.

**Upate 06/01/2019:** try remove selected from **"Settings -> System -> Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"**

**Update 16/01/2019:** Try to use `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default` but **gdm3 Default** never executed on shutdown computer.

**Update 10/05/2023:** I found it is a bug of chrome:
[Issue 429404: Chrome didn't shutdown correctly every time after reboot](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429404)

Comment: I would reinstall Chrome.  Usually when I have a repeated issue like this it is due to some sort of configuration corruption.

Comment: Reinstalling Chrome is completely irrelevant advice for this issue. Chrome needs to be stopped prior to the desktop environment being stopped. Essentially what is needed is a more up to date version of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/604709/7143 but for Ubuntu 18.04 where lightdm is no longer in use.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 1 Mar 2019**

This bug has now been [marked as fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429404#c74) and expected to ship in Chrome 74 or later:

---

Taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063532/7143), you need to add the following line into your `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default`:

```
killall -HUP chrome
```

Note you will need root (eg. sudo) access to edit that `Default` file.

Comment: This didn't work, I tried with reboot and shutdown, and chrome still ask about to restore last session. any other advice ?

Comment: sorry I didnt actually get a chance to fully test this when I posted, just ran the script directly and you are correct, it still seems to run too late. Looking at the docs it seems that the X server is already gone by this stage so thats probably why:help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#scripting I'll need to do some more reasch to try to find a point early enough to do this

Comment: actually this looks like some sort of bug in gdm3 as it appears that /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default never actually gets run when shuting down! Its been reported in other questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072616/etc-gdm3-postsession-default-not-executed  but Im not really prepared to take the derasitc measures suggested in that answer.

Comment: Thanks @Maks for your time, effort and help in this, I will continue searching a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 5 April 2022**

My issue was similar but with ***Brave browser***. After more than an hour of research on the internet and after reading the various comments, this solution is almost the right one.

---

Setup:

**OS**: Pop!_OS 21.10 x86_64
**Kernel**: 5.16.15-76051615-generic
**Brave Browser** 100.1.37.109
**DE**: GNOME 40.5

---

Sometimes we are directed to the ***/etc/rc6.d*** folder by creating the ***K99_script*** file without the ***.sh*** but this solution did not help me in my case. [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/416301/1013655)

So I started to do the solution of But but it didn't work. So I looked if I had the same result by launching the command directly in a terminal and it was the case. And until I simply send the following command:

```
$ killall brave
```

Brave browser did not ask me to restore my tabs. So I confirmed what was the solution that worked with this command and it was [Maks](https://askubuntu.com/users/7143/maks) solution but without any argument.

Complete procedure

```
$ cat /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default
# For add line before "exit 0"
$ sudo sed -i '/^exit 0.*/i killall brave' /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default
$ cat /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default
```

You can reboot and your browser won't ask you to restore tabs

> *When the user terminates his session, the **PostSession** script will be run. Again operation is similar to **Init**, **PostLogin** and **PreSession**. Again the script will be run with root privileges, the slave daemon will block and the **$USER** environment variable will contain the name of the user who just logged out and **$DISPLAY** will be set to the display the user used, however note that the X server for this display may already be dead and so you shouldn't try to access it. Also **$X_SERVERS** environmental variable is set and this points to a fake generated x servers file for use with the sessreg accounting program.*
> [source](https://www.jirka.org/gdm-documentation/x241.html)

---

**if the problem persists it may be due to a browser extension** : [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011880/1013655)

Comment: Hello. Pop OS is not Ubuntu. Do you know for fact this works on Ubuntu?

Comment: Pop OS is based on Ubuntu and Debian https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=popos but this step work just with Gnome because GDM is GNOME Display Manager https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager

Comment: Sorry noting you can say will change the site rules. Pop OS is not supported.