# GRUB randomly showing on startup

Tags: boot, grub2

I have set GRUB to be fully hidden. However, it does sometimes randomly show when I am booting. What could  be causing this?

Contents of etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

Ubuntu 18.04. is the only installed operating system. I am using UEFI boot with secure boot disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to occur when Grub went into recovery mode after the system or a program didn't shut down properly.

To prevent Grub from showing in those circumstances add this line to /etc/default/grub

GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="3"

Set the timeout value to anything you like. I have set it to 3 to still have the option to access group in case of system failure. Setting the value to 0 will prevent Grub from showing altogether.

After making the changes run this command to apply them:
sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
```

in `/etc/default/grub` but you also have the line

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`.

With the first one you tell Grub to hide the menu and with the latter you tell Grub to show the menu after 0 seconds.

You should remove the line

```
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
```

from `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Here the essential part from the [GRUB Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration):

> ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT’
>
> Wait this many seconds before displaying the menu. If ESC is pressed during 
>      that time, display the menu and wait for input according to ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’. If >    a hotkey associated with a menu entry is pressed, boot the associated menu 
>      entry immediately. If the timeout expires before either of these happens, 
>      display the menu for the number of seconds specified in ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’ before 
>      booting the default entry.
>
> If you set ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT’, you should also set ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT=0’ so that >    the menu is not displayed at all unless ESC is pressed.
>
> This option is unset by default, and is deprecated in favour of the less 
>      confusing ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown’ or ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden’.

---

Another possibility is Grub's built-in `recordfail`-function. Whenever a menu-entry is chosen (manually or automatically), Grub will set the variable `recordfail=1` and saves it in `/boot/grub/grubenv`.

During boot the variable will be unset by systemd if the boot is successful, if the boot fails, the variable will remain unchanged in `/boot/grub/grubenv`.

Everytime time Grub starts, Grub will read `/boot/grub/grubenv` and checks if `recordfail` is set to `1`. So Grub will know if the last boot succeeded or not. If the last boot wasn't successful, Grub will override your settings from `/etc/default/grub` to display the boot menu for 30 seconds.

You can check the content of `/boot/grub/grubenv` with

```
cat /boot/grub/grubenv
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It looks like this fixed it.

Comment: No, sorry I have to retract that. Grub still comes up at random. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @phanky5 Does it really happen randomly or can you determine special circumstances, e.g the boot menu appears after the system failed to boot?

Comment: I will take some paper notes and report back here. This may take a few days to figure it out.

Comment: After you last comment this was easy to figure out. It was a known issue with Chrome browser not shutting down properly: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429404#c74
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103495/want-chrome-close-normally-when-shutdown-or-reboot-ubuntu-18-04

I have moved to Firefox and the problem is now fixed. Thank you for your help.